# Zipped .wav file only on my pc available (C#)

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I need to submit a program for my study. I would like to attach background music. This was done, but my teacher will not be able to play the sound because the .wav file refers to the location on my PC. Even if I would zip the whole C# program and include the .wav file, it won't work.

How can I refer to the file so that anyone with the zipped file can also have the music?

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer playSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Gebruiker1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Reversi nieuw\ReversiMusic.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access the file using a relative path, for instance in the same directory as the application:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer playSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"ReversiMusic.wav");
```

In visual studio you can add the .wav file to your project and select "Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer" to ensure that it is placed next to the executable file when building your project.

Comment: I thought of this but it gives me an error: '' An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.dll ''    Also, where can I select your suggestion of "Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer" ?

Comment: After adding the .wav to your project, select it and it should appear in the properties window. I don't know if this is the same for all versions of VS btw. If you can't find it you can always copy the .wav file to the bin\Debug and bin\Release folders manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would import the sound file into your resources and then play it using something like this:

```
Stream str = global::ProjectName.Properties.Resources.WavFile;
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(str);
            player.Play();
```